# Can I connect an electronic air cleaner to the 24v terminals of my furnace?

Tags: furnace

I have a Goodman GKS90904CX furnace and looking to install an Electro Breeze Air Cleaner.  The air cleaner needs an R and C 24v terminal for power or a power outlet with the supplied transformer.  I would prefer to power it from the Furnace directly so I don't have to run an extension cord from the power outlet which is being used by the Sump Pump.

Can I connect the R and C wires from the Electronic Air Cleaner to the same R & C terminals on the Furnace (picture below) that is being used by the Thermostat and AC unit?  I'm not sure if fancier furnaces have dedicated 24v terminals for Electronic air cleaners or if the same terminals can be used.

[image]

Comment: Some furnaces have terminals for accessories, check the documentation to see if yours offers terminals for an air cleaner. If not, you're probably better off using the transformer that came with the air cleaner. As Longneck points out, you can install the transformer in or on the furnace.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, yes, R and C are the 24 volt and common terminals of the transformer.

However, you have to make sure you do not draw more current than the transformer can handle. These things are usually rated in volt-amps. If your furnace, air handler and air conditioning compressor are marked with their ratings, you can tell how much power you can spare. Don't exceed 80% of the rated capacity of your transformer.

As an alternative, you can mount the transformer that came with your air cleaner in/on your air handler. Locate the existing transformer and you can wire the new one in to the same 120 volt lines.

Comment: Why shouldn't you exceed 80% of the transformer capacity?

Comment: Age. In my experience, older parts will tend to use more current and older transformers tend to provide less than their rated capacity.

Comment: Derating, in general, improves the safety factor of components and systems.  How much and how little to derate is a complicated mix of engineering and economic factors.  What is appropriate for a space mission will probably be too much for consumer appliances.  Buying certified devices (UL, CSA) is one way to know the device has had some 3rd party scrutiny.